# How to round google maps in Webkit

Tags: google-maps, css

I have a container for google maps, and I round that container.

Happy in firefox, very sad in Webkit. How do I make everyone happy?

#### CSS

```
.contact.words .map {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 410px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  width: 209px;
}
```

#### HTML (before google)

```
<div class="map"></div>
```

Example:
http://staging.studiobloo.com/#!contact

Please,
I just want to see them smile again.